# Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition() not giving output

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

This is my code on Titanium Appcelerator:

```
  function ApplicationWindow(title) {
    var self = Ti.UI.createWindow({
        title:title,
        backgroundColor:'white'
    });

        var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
        height:44,
        width:200,
        title:L('openWindow'),
        top:200
    });


    self.add(button);

    function getPosition() {
        alert("In the Function");
        Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
                    Titanium.Geolocation.distanceFilter = 10;
                    Ti.Geolocation.preferredProvider = "gps";

                    if (e.error) {
                        Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                            title: L('geolocate_failure'),
                            message: e.error
                        }).show();
                        return;
                    }
                    var found = new Object();
                    locateIndicator.show();
                    found.longitude = e.coords.longitude;
                    found.latitude = e.coords.latitude;
                    found.altitude = e.coords.altitude;
                    found.heading = e.coords.heading;
                    found.accuracy = e.coords.accuracy;
                    found.speed = e.coords.speed;
                    found.timestamp = e.coords.timestamp;
                    found.altitudeAccuracy = e.coords.altitudeAccuracy;
                    return found
                });
    }

 button.addEventListener('click', function() {
        alert("button click");
        getPosition();
    });
    return self;
};

module.exports = ApplicationWindow;
```

When I am Running this code in Android Emulator it is giving a pop up reading "**Location is currently unavailable**."
Does this mean until I run this code on a mobile(GPS Enabled) It wont give me any GPS Related output ? or it is something with my code ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run geo location service in your emulator then you have to set  latitude and longitude in ddms.